# React: using React component inside of dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about using React. As you can see from the title, I'm wondering if it is possible to use React component (that is created by `React.createClass`) inside of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property. I have tried, but React just prints code without transformation like this:

```
const MySubComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<p>MySubComponent</p>);
    }
});

...

let myStringHTML;
myStringHTML += "<ul>";
myStringHTML += "    <li>";
myStringHTML += "        <MySubComponent />";
myStringHTML += "    </li>";
myStringHTML += "</ul>";

const MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myStringHTML}}></div>
        );
    }
});
```

I expected

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>MySubComponent</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but the code is just same as original string, and that means React didn't transform `MySubComponent`.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Above example is just simple but my actual code is quite complicated. It will be very thanks gimme a hand ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` expects a JS object with `__html` property which should be valid HTML markup. Instead you are providing `<MySubComponent />` there and expecting it to render that component's html. React won't process `<MySubComponent />` there. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as name suggests should be avoided. Moreover what you are trying to accomplish here can easily be done through React only.

```
const MySubComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<li><p>MySubComponent {this.props.index}</p></li>);
    }
});

const MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        let subComponentList = [];
        [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(i){
            subComponentList.push(<MySubComponent key={i} index={i} />);
        }); 
        return (
            <ul>{subComponentList}</ul>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, mountNode);
```

Comment: thanks. i also thought using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" bad because of name ;)

Answer (score 9):

Old question but for future wonderers I think I might have a solution to this but do note that this will definitely break your `redux` flow if you're using it in your project.

Basically, you should have some `id` in your `dangerousSetInnerHTML` text.
The idea is to mount to that `id` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook after your "dangerous HTML" has been mounted to DOM.

e.g.

```
const myStringHTML = `
  <div id="someid">
    some text in my dangerous html
  </div>
`;

const MySubComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<p>MySubComponent</p>);
    }
});

...

let myStringHTML;
myStringHTML += "<ul>";
myStringHTML += "    <li>";
myStringHTML += "        <MySubComponent />";
myStringHTML += "    </li>";
myStringHTML += "</ul>";

const MyComponent = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
      ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector('#someid'));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: myStringHTML}}></div>
        );
    }
});
```

Do note that `componentDidMount` will however not be called on component updates. For more info on this refer to the [lifecycle hook of react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Fair warning though that this does feel *hacky* and it is. This also has its limitations as I mentioned some above but there can be time where you *have* no other option but to use `dangerousSetInnerHTML` and at times like this, this is an option. At other times do what @Rohit Singh Sengar suggested and try to do it in `react`.

Comment: Just a heads up - you can't use componentDidMount in functional React components as shown here, you can use useEffect hook instead. It's not absolutely the same since useEffect runs after the component is painted on the screen whereas componentDidMount runs before, but it's the closest thing to it in functional components.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to open a react portal. Ensure that the element has rendered and then simply

`ReactDOM.createPortal(<YourComponent>,document.querySelector('selector'));`

This is the cleanest way so far i have found to achieve this.