# React component inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I need to get an HTML string.
(From the server or from the user input, maybe something processed from markdown, in any case, it seems I really need to use `setDangerousHtml`.)

But I also need some react components inside that part.
For example, I would transform some links to `Link` from react-router; or I have something inside the HTML like `<myWidget:12345>` to a react component `<MyWidget id="12345" text=this.props.text >`.

What is the react-way for doing this?

Comment: Why do you need to get what seems to be a view string from the server? Ideally the server should only give you data which you then fit into your client-side components to render the view.

Comment: For example, I would like to write an app where the user can edit articles using markdown, so it is a string in markdown format. But I also need some customized tag in the string, that I'd love to render to special react component in my app.

Comment: Right, so, the only thing your server should be giving you is 1) the initial state of the markdown form, and 2) an acknowledgement of saving any changes made to the form. This can easily be done via JSON responses for example. There is no reason your server should be sending you back HTML/React strings when it's not the initial render. If you have parts of the markdown that should be rendered via their own component the front-end should handle that parsing.

Comment: The server sends the article in markdown, with some special tags (or in the other situation, the user edits it and wants a preview). Now reactjs needs to render this article on screen.

Comment: So again, have the front-end parse the markdown. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking about doing that now. Let me confirm, do you mean parse the markdown then use js to generate a tree of components according to whatever the parsed result is? That is quite some work. Originally I wanted to use some library e.g. `marked`, which gives me a rendered html string that I can `setDangerousHtml`.

Comment: Either works (and your way as you mention is likely much simpler), but if you get a rendered HTML string it won't be React components, which is fine.

Comment: That was the problem.:( I need some part in the html really be react components.

Comment: @user715353 a little too late but I answered something similar here too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688007/1204312. Worth the shot.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to approach this problem is using `RenderToString` function. Convert the component that you want to insert into a string like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent.jsx';

var MyComponentString = renderToString(MyComponent);
```

Now concat this string into the string that's coming from the API wherever you want. Use basic string manipulation functions to achieve that.

Then, use `setDangerousHtml` to achieve the final new DOM. Although this might not be the recommended way for doing this, because `RenderToString` isn't supposed to be used in browser, it'll work.

Comment: I think this does not feel right, but is lovely..:) I will give it a try at least to see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this and some other hacks, and they all end up with the same error: turns out I need to passdown the whole context (in my case, MuiProvider, store provider, router, etc.) to the components inside the HTML. Is there an easy way to get around this?